# Can't subset column even if the column exists using SELECT from DPLYR package

Tags: r, select, dplyr, kaggle

I'm subsetting a data frame having 19 columns. When I add **CRIMINALCASES** to the select() option it's showing an error.

```
data_1 <- data_kerala%>%
select(CONSTITUENCY, NAME, WINNER, PARTY, GENDER,CRIMINALCASES, AGE, CATEGORY, EDUCATION)
```

This is the error message

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ The column `CRIMINALCASES` doesn't exist.
Traceback:

1. data_kerala %>% select(CONSTITUENCY, NAME, WINNER, PARTY, GENDER, 
 .     CRIMINALCASES, AGE, CATEGORY, EDUCATION)
2. withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
3. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4. eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
5. `_fseq`(`_lhs`)
6. freduce(value, `_function_list`)
7. withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
8. function_list[[k]](value)
9. select(., CONSTITUENCY, NAME, WINNER, PARTY, GENDER, CRIMINALCASES, 
 .     AGE, CATEGORY, EDUCATION)
10. select.data.frame(., CONSTITUENCY, NAME, WINNER, PARTY, GENDER, 
  .     CRIMINALCASES, AGE, CATEGORY, EDUCATION)
11. tidyselect::vars_select(tbl_vars(.data), !!!enquos(...))
12. eval_select_impl(NULL, .vars, expr(c(!!!dots)), include = .include, 
  .     exclude = .exclude, strict = .strict, name_spec = unique_name_spec, 
  .     uniquely_named = TRUE)
13. with_subscript_errors(vars_select_eval(vars, expr, strict, data = x, 
  .     name_spec = name_spec, uniquely_named = uniquely_named, type = type), 
  .     type = type)
14. tryCatch(instrument_base_errors(expr), vctrs_error_subscript = function(cnd) {
  .     cnd$subscript_action <- subscript_action(type)
  .     cnd$subscript_elt <- "column"
  .     cnd_signal(cnd)
  . })
15. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
16. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
17. value[[3L]](cond)
18. cnd_signal(cnd)
19. rlang:::signal_abort(x)
```

Don't understand why it is saying the **column don't exist**

[image: Here is a snap of the data set]

Here are the column names using the function colnames()

[image: Column names of the data set]

This is the list of column names as shown is Kaggle

[image]

Then tried adding space between the words but no use

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Sorry, I can't leave a comment since I'm a newbie to StackOverflow.)

Is it possible that the column name is actually CRIMINAL CASES (with a space) or CRIMINAL\nCASES?

Could you try `CRIMINAL\nCASES` wrapped in backticks (`)?

The following worked for me without issues:

```
# creating test tibble
a <- 
  tribble(
  ~"CRIMINAL\nCASES", ~"random",
  "hi", "bye"
)

a %>%
  select(`CRIMINAL\nCASES`)
```

Comment: Hi @lazypanda thanks for the answer, I tried 'CRIMINAL\nCASES' wrapped in backticks and it worked.